# How should I have changed my question to avoid a close?

Tags: support

I asked this question: [Considerations when using Gulp to compile typescript vs using Visual Studio](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/321462/8939)

I do agree that my initial question (before edits) was outside of programmers.stackexchange, and after I received a comment from a moderator, I edited my question to make it more objective.

The reason given for closing does not seem to line up with the question.  The reason claims that I asked for anecdotal experience, when really I'm asking for objective give and take between one methodology and another.

According to the FAQ, I can ask questions about development processes and methodologies (which is why I asked on Programmers, and not on SO)

I suspect that what really happened here is that there was a vote to close before my initial edit, and then it was eventually closed by "me too" close votes.

If I'm wrong about that and my edits did not bring the question into alignment with the site, I would like to know what more I might have done to have made the question suitable.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the problem with "Pros and Cons"?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/what-is-the-problem-with-pros-and-cons)

Comment: Thank you, but I'm going to politely disagree on the grounds that my question was much more narrow in scope than the example of "Linux vs BSD development environment".

Some responses that I think would have been valuable and not at all subjective would have been things like:
1.  Using Visual Studio integration, MSBuild will compile your ts files
2.  Using gulp, you will need an additional solution to get source maps because tsc does not generate them for you.
etc.  

I think that it's unfortunate that we can't ask that on stack, because it's valuable info to have.

Comment: The proper close reason would be POB or too broad, not the one actually used.

Comment: @Snowman if memory serves too broad was my pick. Other voters could have chosen tool recommendation because it reads like asking to recommend Gulp or VS

Answer (score 2):

The model for Stack Exchange is "ask a specific question, get a specific answer."  Pros and cons questions fail this model, regardless of their scope.

Questions like yours are not about any specific problem; rather, they ask the answerer to provide a treatise on his expertise in the problem domain.  This is fundamentally at odds with the Q&A model, which seeks to build a repository of useful questions and answers that target specific, real-life problems.

Product recommendation questions fail the model for essentially the same reasons: there can be too many possible answers, and the answers so provided tend to be opinion-based and not fact-based.  That a "pros and cons" question asks for "criteria to decide," or limits it decision to only two things instead of many, doesn't make it any less of a product recommendation.  If anything, such an approach only underscores the fundamental problem with such questions, which is that (even if such questions were on-topic) the person asking the question should *already have a fair idea what their selection criteria is.*

In other words, these are questions that not only ask "what decision should I make," but also "how should I go about making it?"  In my opinion, such questions are premature for a Q&A site, what I would colloquially call "not fully baked."  They are the very definition of "Too Broad."  At the end of the day decisions like these are going to depend greatly on factors that you haven't told us anything about, such as your team's relative experience.